# Variable module fields

Tags: ansible

How can I set a custom key for a module?
What I want to do:

```
module:
  "{{ var }}": ...
```

The above raises an error, "Unsupported parameters for module: {{ var }}".

This is useful for me for example setting the iptables:

```
iptables:
  "{{ item.key }}": lo
with_items:
  - { key: in_interface }
  - { key: out_interface }
```

I am new to Ansible; looking around, I did not find a solution.

Comment: What are you going to do with this key, in/out_interface:? If you want to use it in module iptables, then use variables.

Comment: You can't use like that. Use set fact or variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a jinja2 template expression as a yaml hasmap key: it will not be interpreted, as you found out.

I made reproducible examples for my propositions with the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-module) (this is just for illustration, there are much simpler and better way to acheive the same result in those specific cases).

## Proposition 1: hacky with ansible warnings

A hacky way to do things similarly as you tried would be to declare all parameters of your module in a constructed var where you can use jinja2 templating.

```
---
- name: Test dynamic parameters
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set atime and mtime of file sequentially
      file: "{{ {'path': '/tmp/test_dynparm.txt', 'state': 'touch', item: '201901010000.00'} }}"
      loop:
        - access_time
        - modification_time
```

This gives the following result

```
TASK [Set atime and mtime of file sequentially] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Using a variable for a task's 'args' is unsafe in some situations (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe)

changed: [localhost] => (item=access_time)
changed: [localhost] => (item=modification_time)

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see, this works but you get a warning from ansible that it is not possible to turn off, because passing module parameters in a var [can be unsafe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/faq.html#argsplat-unsafe). Moreover, in your case, you would have to quote all over static keys and values you want to pass to the module.

## Proposition 2: no warnings and probably easier to maintain

My preferred solution would be to write down the static module parameters in pure yaml, pass the optional parameters in the loop variable and use the [`default`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) or [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) filter.

```
---
- name: Test dynamic parameters
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Set atime and mtime of file sequentially
      vars:
        time: 201901010000.00
      file:
        path: '/tmp/test_dynparm.txt'
        state: 'touch'
        access_time: "{{ item.access_time | default(omit) }}"
        modification_time: "{{ item.modification_time | default(omit) }}"
      loop:
        - access_time: "{{ time }}"
        - modification_time: "{{ time }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [Test dynamic parameters] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Set atime and mtime of file sequentially] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'access_time': 201901010000.0})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'modification_time': 201901010000.0})

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```